# Prove/Disprove if $B$ is bounded from below so $A$ is bounded from below

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> Prove/Disprove: If $A\subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and if $B$ is bounded from below so $A$ is bounded from below

Proof: Let's take $x\in A$, because $A\subseteq B$ so, for all $x\in A$, $x\in B$.

$B$ is bounded from below which means, $\forall b\in B, n\leq b$.

Therefore also all $x,n\leq x$ and $n\leq A$ which means $A$ is bounded from below.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Your proof is correct, but maybe not formulated to its best. BUt th idea is indeed that any bound for $B$ is a fortiori also a bound for $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better:

Proof: Since $B$ is bounded below, there is a $n\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $n\leq b$ for all $b\in B$.

Now, let $x\in A$. Since $x\in A\subseteq B$, we have $n\leq x$.

Since $x\in  A$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $A$ is bounded below by $n$.

Comment: Even better: First pick $n$ once and for all. Then show that this one $n$ is a lower bound for $A$ (by considering arbitrary $x\in A$). Pikcing $n$after $x$ makes the argument fishy